# Get files from disk filtering by size

Tags: c#, file-system

does anyone knows how I can simplify this code?

The objective is to get multiple files from the explorer and validate the number of files, the weight of each file and the total weight.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<StorageFile>> GetMultipleFileFromDisk(Window rootWindow, int maxFiles,
            string fileTypes = null, ulong fileMaxSize = 0, ulong totalMaxSize = 0,
            PickerLocationId? pickerLocation = null, PickerViewMode viewMode = PickerViewMode.List)
        {
            var filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            if (fileTypes != null)
            {
                var fileTypesArray = fileTypes.Split(";");
                //IList<string> fileTypesList = fileTypes.Split(";");

                // Get the current window's Handler by passing in the Window object
                var handler = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(rootWindow);

                // Associate the HWND with the file picker
                WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(filePicker, handler);

                if (fileTypesArray.Count() >= 0)
                    foreach (var fileType in fileTypesArray)
                        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(fileType);
            }

            filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = pickerLocation ?? PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
            filePicker.ViewMode = viewMode;

            var files = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
            if (files.Count > maxFiles)
                throw new Exception($"Só pode carregar {maxFiles} ficheiros.");

            IEnumerable<StorageFile> finalFiles;

            if (fileMaxSize != 0)
            {
                var correctFiles = new List<StorageFile>();
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                   
                    var hasRightSize = await HasRightSize(file, fileMaxSize);
                    if (hasRightSize)
                        correctFiles.Add(file);
                    else
                        throw new Exception(file.Name + " excede o tamanho máximo.");
                }
                finalFiles = correctFiles;
            } else
                finalFiles = files;

            if (totalMaxSize <= 0) return finalFiles;
            if (!await HasRightSize(finalFiles, totalMaxSize))
                finalFiles = null;

            return finalFiles;
        }
```

Comment: The naming guidelines clearly state that you should not call something a xxxxList or xxxArray etc.: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines . If you have more than one book, you would call that "books", not "bookList" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my refactoring ideas

#### The `if(fileTypes != null)` block

```
if (fileTypes != null)
{
    var handler = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(rootWindow);
    WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(filePicker, handler);
        
    foreach (var fileType in fileTypes.Split(";"))
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(fileType);
}
```

- You don't need to put the result of `Split` into a variable, like `fileTypesArray`

  - You can use it directly inside the `foreach` loop
- You don't need to guard your `foreach` loop with an empty collection check

  - If it is empty then it will not execute the loop body
  - If the `Split` could return `null` (but it couldn't) then it would make sense to guard it with a null check

#### The `if (fileMaxSize != 0)` block

```
IEnumerable<StorageFile> finalFiles = files;
if (fileMaxSize != 0)
{
    var correctFiles = new List<StorageFile>();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (!await HasRightSize(file, fileMaxSize))
            throw new Exception(file.Name + " excede o tamanho máximo.");
        correctFiles.Add(file);
    }
    finalFiles = correctFiles;
}
```

- You can omit the outer `else` branch by initializing the `finalFiles` with the `files`
- You can omit the inner `else` branch by inverting the if condition since the `throw` statement breaks the execution

  - So, it will not reach the `Add` command if it does not have the right size

Based on your requirements it might make sense to use a more specific exception (either a built-in or a custom one).

#### The final `return` statements

```
if (totalMaxSize <= 0)
    return finalFiles;

return await HasRightSize(finalFiles, totalMaxSize) ? finalFiles : null;
```

Or

```
return totalMaxSize <= 0
        ? finalFiles
        : await HasRightSize(finalFiles, totalMaxSize)
            ? finalFiles
            : null;
```

- You can take advantage of the ternary conditional operator to make your statements more concise
- I depends on personal preference whether the latter option, with the nested conditional operator, is more legible than the former one